# Does the arm that connects a camp stove to a 1 lb. propane canister have an appropriate regulator for a 20 lb tank?

Tags: propane

I am trying to connect a 20 lb. propane tank to a small camp stove, one intended to operate with a 1 lb. canister of propane.

I purchased a 4' hose that is purportedly "designed to connect a 20 lb. tank to devices intended to use a 1 lb. tank."  In the picture, (1) is where the hose would connect to the 20 lb. tank, (2) is where the other end of the hose connects to the arm that hold the canister, and (3) is where the arm connects to the stove itself.

[image]

Assuming that I set up in a safe spot outdoors and use soapy water to test for leaks, etc., is this setup safe?

My only concern is that there won't be a pressure regulator attached to the 20 lb. tank.  It seems like this is necessary.  The manual for the stove refers to the arm as the "regulator."  Is it rated to handle the pressure from a 20 lb. tank?

Comment: About the only thing I know about propane/gas is when things go wrong, you can get a big boom.  Adding a stove made for one pound tanks to a 20 pound tank without expert advice, might not be a good idea.

Comment: Back when we did a lot of tent camping, I purchased a "bulk adapter" from Coleman that did exactly this. They sold a smaller 5? lb refillable tank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no pressure difference between a 1 pound propane cylinder and a 2000 pound propane cylinder if both are at the same temperature.

1 looks like it would fit a 20 pound tank.  If it fits it's fine.

2 looks like the regulator.  I would expect it to either have a documented setting or be adjustable.

Comment: Affirmative: the big chunk at #2 would have to be the regulator. Because this part is proprietary for the stove I would expect it to be neither labeled nor adjustable.